# How to copy select queried field name in JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: attributes, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

In MySQL Workbench, we can copy attribute name after performing the select query like this how to copy field name in the DataGrip. I am using DataGrip version 2018.3.1.

For example: from the below image I want to copy `ClearanceTranID` attribute:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Click the query result in the console and then press `ctrl+f12` and then try to write expected column name and press `esc` and then press `ctrl+c` and finally press `esc` to close the window

Comment: @w3outlook you meant `Ctrl+C` but not `esc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press Ctrl+F12, it will show you the column list.
2. Navigate to the column you need (you can start typing a name and the quick search will be activated)
3. Press Ctrl+C to copy.